# Why is my beef broth the wrong color?

Tags: beef, stock, broth

Beef soup bones were on sale today, so I thought I’d make a broth )(stock?). I roasted the bones for a couple of hours, then added them to the pot along with some onion, celery, and mushroom stems. As it came to a boil, there was virtually no scum to skim.

The broth is milky white. I can’t seem to get a beef broth with characterstic dark golden brown color that characterizes a French onion soup base.

Comment: Did you peel the onions? And can we get a picture, please?

Comment: I only removed the flaky skin from the onion, the stuff that just comes off when you pick the onion up. I do have a pic, but I have no idea how to upload it! Have you ever had tonkotsu ramen? That’s kinda what it looks like.

Comment: What temp did you roast the bones at?  I wonder if the bones themselves didn't roast hot enough to get a good dark color, so the broth came out a bit pale.  Also, how long did you simmer your stock for?

Comment: I roasted the bones at 350°F for about two and a half hours.

Comment: You can leave the flaky skin on the onions and that will help color the stock some. You can also try roasting your bones at a higher temp (400 deg F) if you think browning may be an issue. 350 deg. is considered the minimum temp for browning foods.

Comment: The marrow inside the bones is what gives the stock its color, although I usually put some browned meat in too and brown the vegetables. Did someone scoop out the marrow before selling you the bones? Marrow has a lot of fat, so there would have been a layer of fat on the top too.

Comment: Most of the bones had marrow in them. Apparently the fat (what I didn’t skim off) was emulsified into the broth because of the boiling action. It’s not a greasy broth at all, though; more creamy.

Comment: If you are going to worry about the color of the beef broth, then you should post a photograph of the beef broth on this website, so that we can look at it.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by OP in a comment, it is likely that a milky, creamy broth is the result of fat emulsifying into the broth due to too-violently boiling the broth. For context: when making a Tonkotsu ramen broth, this style of milky broth (typically made with pork rather than beef bones) is often the desired result, hence you'll find recipes calling for a [sustained rolling boil](https://glebekitchen.com/tonkotsu-ramen-broth-home/) for hours (whereas traditional French stocks would be kept at a simmer), or even suggestions to [blend up your broth](https://www.reddit.com/r/ramen/comments/7z6zcb/tonkotsu_ramen_balance_between_white_broth_and/).

Thus, the answer to this question would be to cook the broth at a [simmer](https://www.cooksillustrated.com/how_tos/10660-cooking-class-boil-versus-simmer), rather than a rolling boil.

Answer (score 0):

It actually may be due to marrow, did you use marrow bones? If this is the case, the broth will be all the more nutritious.